# How do I access my model (or other state in the App struct) from a ComplicationController when using SwiftUI lifecycle?

Tags: swiftui, watchkit

Given a SwiftUI Watch App:

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var model = SomeModel()

    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
            .environmentObject(model)
        }

        WKNotificationScene(controller: NotificationController.self, category: "myCategory")
    }
}
```

How do I gain access to `model` in my ComplicationController? Tried using `EnvironmentObject` as below without success.

```
class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: SomeModel
...
```

Deeper question is what is the relative lifecycles of the App struct and the ComplicationsController. I have a heavy model and I only want to instantiate it once. Does it just belong as a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `SomeModel` is a single state object of the app, then you can just make it shared and access explicitly, like shown below

```
class SomeModel: ObservableObject {
   static let shared = SomeModel()
 
   // ... other code
```

so

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var model = SomeModel.shared    // << here
...
```

and

```
class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    var model = SomeModel.shared // << here 
...
```

*Note: `EnvironmentObject` works only in SwiftUI views, so in `ComplicationController` it is useless (or even harmful)*